# On $C^1$ Transformation in Change of variables in an integral

Tags: calculus

In [Stewart's Calculus book](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/media/16_home.php), an argument is given to intuitively explain why the theorem for change of variables, using Jacobian matrix, is valid without giving the full proof.

However, there are parts that I have little intuition over and would like to understand more coherently. I would appreciate it if someone explains them to me and preferably, if it is not too hard, by giving the exact proof.

1. What is it about $C^1$ Transformation that is of interest to us?
2. Why should $T$ (the $C^1$ transformation) map one region to another region (and not to multiple one)? Is this because of $C^1$ transformation?
3. In Example 1: "The transformation maps the boundary of S into the boundary of the image" - I know this is not generally true. But where is it true? And how do we know that it is in this particular example?
4. By moving around the boundary in the counterclockwise direction, we also move around the boundary of the image in the counterclockwise direction. Why is this true?

[from text_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbf21.png)

[from text_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fnah.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. In the formula you have a derivative, and the product of that derivative and another function inside an integral. Therefore, you also need that that product can be integrated. These two conditions don't require that the change of variable has a derivative everywhere, and it doesn't require that that derivative is continuous. The condition can be relaxed [somewhat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Proposition), and even a bit more than in that link. The existence of continuous derivatives ...

Comment: ... gives you control on the derivative through the values of the function $f(a)-f(b)=f'(c)(a-b)$. And when the derivative is continuous you get even more, since that $f'(c)$ is bounded, uniformly continuous, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand why using $C^1$ transformation is desirable. 
But what about 3 & 4?

Comment: 2. This is a property of all continuous functions. You don't need the $C^1$ property. If you have a connected set, and you apply a continuous function, then the image is connected. This has been proven in this site several times. [Here is one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279770/image-of-a-connected-space-under-a-continuous-map-is-connected-proof)

Comment: 3. In Example that property of mapping the boundary to the boundary can be checked directly. You can compute the images of the boundary, as they did there, and you could compute the image of the interior points directly and verify that they fall inside the previously computed image of the boundary. That part, being Stewart's, they didn't do. Since you are using that awful book I know your calculus course is doomed to be a bad one. There reason behind that property is [the open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)). The $T$ in that example ...

Comment: ... is the function $u+iv\mapsto (u+iv)^2=(u^2-v^2)+2uvi$. The form of the example was chosen on purpose, but instead of informing you Stewart keeps you in the dark. The Jacobian of this functions is non-zero in the points of the region, at least the interior ones. So, the open mapping theorem implies that the interior points are mapped to interior points, and therefore boundary points to boundary points.

Comment: 4. This can also be checked directly by moving $x$ in the parametrizations $[4]$ and $[5]$ and using the monotonicity of those functions. But in a larger picture is also due to the change of variable being the square function in the complex numbers.